# Creating extension method for all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My context class looks this:

```
public virtual DbSet<MyTableItem> MyTableItems { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<MyTableProduct> MyTableProducts { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<MyTableKid> MyTableKids { get; set; }
```

And these tables all have different columns.

I want to create an extension method that will check if a name already exists and if it does it will increment it so that it will give me a unique name for a specific column. So if I call it for the MyTableItem which has item_name column, it will look in the values of the item_name column, for MyTableProduct table it will look in the prod_name column, etc.

This is my current method:

```
public static string GetUniqueName<T>(this DbContext db, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string columnName, string defaultName) where T : class
{
    var counter = 0;

    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "source");
    var nameFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(source, columnName), Expression.Constant(defaultName)), source);

    while (db.Set<T>().Where(nameFilter).FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        counter++;
        nameFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(source, columnName), Expression.Constant(defaultName + " (" + counter + ")")), source);
    }

    return defaultName + " (" + counter + ")";
}
```

And this works, however I don't like that this is an extension method for the whole dbContext class. I think it is better if it's for each of the tables.

Comment: That's very inefficient; you're recompiling a new lambda & round-tripping to SQL server in each iteration.  And you can have collisions.

Comment: @SLaks I won't have round-trips, first I will take all names from the table and then iterate through the list in memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because question about improving *working* code are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an extension method on IQueryable itself? Something like this:

```
public static string GetUniqueName<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> nameSelector, string prefix)
{
    var lastName = query.Select(nameSelector)
        .Where(x => x.StartsWith(prefix))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return prefix + (GetCounter(lastName) + 1);
}

public static int GetCounter(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Implement the retrieval of the counter from the name
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I don't know what constraints you want to pose on your data, so I assumed no names other than the auto-generated names start with the default prefix to keep it simple.